# nicEdit does not behave accordingly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicedit

I integrated nicEdit because it's very light unlike all the other ones that contain hundreds of kb's.

In Chrome it is however causing problems. It for example doesn't save the text into the textarea or make things bold. The problem can be observed at [this website](http://www.posterlion.com/xz/asdfssadfadf) or see below code. Please don't provide a hack like one answerer did because that's not going to help anything.

I have disabled the editor for debugging purposes. You can enable it with your console through new nicEditor().panelInstance('comment');

```
<div class="rdd blog-item">
    <h1><a id="blog-item-title" href="/b/asdfssadfadf">this ia test</a></h1>
    <div class="blog-date">
         Date posted: 2013-03-01
    </div>
    <div class="blog-message">
        <p>
            asdfasdfas
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-keywords">
        Keywords: <a href="/k/dfsa sadfasd adfasf adfas">dfsa sadfasd adfasf adfas</a>
        - <a href="/k/jlk">jlk</a>
    </div>
    <h4>0 Comments</h4>
    <div class="blog-comment blog-new-comment">
        <form id="new_comment" name="new_comment">
            <div class="blog-comment-row">
                <h4></h4>
                <h4>Would you like to place a comment?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-comment-row">
                <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-comment-row">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" title="Enter your name">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-comment-row">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" title="Enter your email">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-comment-row">
                <div class="blog-comment-cell">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="blog-comment-cell">
                    <a class="blog-comment-submit blog-comment-button" href="">Submit</a><br/>
                    Your ip address is 220.245.93.218
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bold problem is caused by CSS inheritance. In your css file remove rdd blog-item span{} and it will work. nicEdit does not save the contents automatically in the textarea. At form submission you therefore have to run: nicEditors.findEditor('comment').saveContent(); to save it

Comment: Thank bro, that totally solved it! You must be a great programmer! I was looking for ages for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can [bind events](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/518/Editor%20Events) on the editor and save it's contents when that event is fired.

When I run this code on your example page, it works for me (your server doesn't pickup the nicEditor HTML tags though):

```
var commentNicEditor = new nicEditor().panelInstance('comment');
commentNicEditor.addEvent("blur", function () {

    commentNicEditor.instanceById('comment').saveContent();

});
```

Updated with jQuery-free solution based on [official documentation](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/518/Editor%20Events).

Comment: are you sure that works? When i execute your code the textarea disappears without any nicedit being displayed...

Comment: I don't want to state the obvious here, but you do use jQuery on your page?

Comment: I hope you'll find it, it's driving me nuts and all the other editors contain i don't know how many kb's and it's funny that the demo works fine

Comment: @bicycle Updated my answer. Should work now. Execute that example in the bottom of your page.

Comment: thanks yeah it's saved now but nicedit still doesn't behave accordingly. Try to make something bold.

Comment: @bicycle That's not your original question. You're probably resetting default CSS rules and thus need a manual rule for `strong { font-weight: bolder; }`

Comment: yes it is because it's only doing that in chrome. I'm not resetting css rules. Otherwise it would do it in other browsers anyway. The bold is only applied when you center for example the text.

Comment: @bicycle Your original problem is solved; Chrome now saves the content to the textarea: "* Chrome it is however causing problems and doesn't save the text into the textarea.*"

Comment: yes indeed, solved partly. not completely. See the *and* I think it is causing a conflict somewhere....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26582/discussion-between-bicycle-and-robin-van-baalen)